# CSS Transitions Inside of the bootstrap carousel

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am using the bootstrap carousel and my code is this

```
    <div class="container">   
    <div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide carousel-fade hidden-phone">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item slide-one active">
                <div class="container">
                    <img src="image/slider-main/one/guitar.png" alt="" />
                    <img src="/image/featured-one.jpg" alt="." />
                    <a href#">b</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item slide-two"><a href="/cat/77/i-heart-love-bumper-stickers">a</a></div>
            <div class="item slide-three">c</div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#carousel-1" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#carousel-1" data-slide="next">›</a>
    </div><!-- carousel -->
    <script>
        $('#carousel-1').carousel({
            interval:6000
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

I want to be able to apply css transitions to the images and links inside the .container tag when the parent class is active.

Basically I want to be able to have a slider that has transitions when the "slide" becomes active and if I could do transitions when active is removed that would be great to but not necessary.

Thanks